# M2 backend theme css not loading

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme

I've created a backend theme from `Mage/backend`. When I deploy the static content, the theme is deployed but in front, the CSS is not shown. I created a `styles.css` file in the CSS folder of the theme.

Maybe I need to declare somewhere the `styles.css` but where?

Comment: try to add in pub and load the page is it woring?

Comment: Where you create a new theme? In which folder?

Comment: We need more information.

Comment: You can declare that css file in Magento_Theme->Layout->default.xml file and put css file in Magento_Theme->Css folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### After installing Magento 2

```
sudo service apache2 restart 

sudo chmod -R 777 var/

sudo chmod -R 777 pub/

sudo service apache2 restart

 sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento

 sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart
```

### Content deploy

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy "on root dir".
```

if it's not working yet

For Ubuntu edit the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

find 
`/var/www/`

Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` under the following section:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks it works well. It was a file permissions problem :/