# Magento 2 - CSS not working properly after installation on MacOS

Tags: magento-2.1, css, installation

I just installed **Magento 2** on my mac using **web setup interface**. I've managed to access the **admin panel** and **storefront** but the CSS of the page does not work properly.

I have tried many of the solutions from similar threads like increasing the **memory limit**. No luck so far.

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: You need to be MUCH more specific on how you installed it, what system you use etc. if you expect any help.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200574/m2-backend-theme-css-not-loading/200577?noredirect=1#comment278139_200577 solution here...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .htaccess file in pub/static/frontend and try. Copy pub/static/frontend/.htaccess file from your local working setup and upload it on the server. Please remove your browser cache if required.

Hope this will work for you.